# delayed signal cause unexpected behavior in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

My program will halt when a signal is incorrect. However, the input signal needs time to regenerate, and the process reuses the old signal. It causes the code stops and cannot resume the operation.

For example

```
process(A,B,startRun) 
begin
if (A = 1) then
    case (B) is
    when 0 => 
        -- do something
    when others =>  
    if(startRun = '1')then
        halt <= '1';
    end if;
end case;
else
    -- do something else
end if;
end process;
```

My problem is when A = 1, but B is the old value, say 1. After B become the new value, halt is always set to 1. The program will stop eventually. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: For one thing it looks as if startRun is missing from the sensitivity list. Alternatively, use a clocked process and synchronous design, and simplify life a lot.

Comment: You should assign halt in every paths (when B = 0, when A /= 1) otherwise you will get a latch.

Comment: Just as a side note: "program will stop eventually" does not make sense in the context of HDL, since, strictly speaking, there is no program. It is a hardware with specific architecture running some signals through it. So nothing can "stop" there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm agree with "Jonathan Drolet". I can't see where you reset the signal `halt` to zero. After you set `halt` , it is always `1` and there is no reset statement.
You can use `else` statements for resetting `halt` to zero whenever halting is not required :

```
process(A,B,startRun) 
begin
    if (A = 1) then
        case (B) is
            when 0 =>
                halt <= '0';
                -- do something
            when others =>  
                if(startRun = '1')then
                    halt <= '1';
                else
                    halt <= '0';
                end if;
        end case;
    else
        halt <= '0';
        -- do something else
    end if;
end process;
```

Also you can reset `halt` to `0` at the beginning of the process, but if (`A = 1` and `B /= 0` and `startRun = '1'`) be sure setting `hlat` to `1` is applied because signals or ports assignment is applied at the end of the process :

```
process(A,B,startRun) 
begin
    halt <= '0';
    if (A = 1) then
        case (B) is
            when 0 =>
                -- do something
            when others =>  
                if(startRun = '1')then
                    halt <= '1';
                end if;
        end case;
    else
        -- do something else
    end if;
end process;
```